# Can I distinguish positional and keyword arguments from inside the called function?

Tags: python

I would like to deprecate an old syntax for a function in a Python library. In order to effectively detect whether someone is using the old syntax, I need to know whether an argument is called positionally or through a keyword. Is there a way to detect this?

As an example, consider this function:

```py
def store(name='', value=0):
    # Some functionality here...
```

Can this function know whether it has been called like this:

```py
store('ben', 5)
```

or like this?

```py
store(name='ben', value=5)
```

Comment: I don't think so. I think it only knows the difference when its a positional and a keyword parameter in the signature. `def foo(positional, keyword=None): pass`

Comment: In a roundabout way you can, with `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: You cannot tell the difference. You *can*, however, modify the definition to force positional arguments (`def store(name='', value=0, /)`) or keyword arguments (`def store(*, name='', value=0)`).

Comment: Please clarify which way of passing the values is deprecated - positional or keyword arguments.

Comment: @chepner That is some cool syntax that I didn't know yet. Thanks for sharing! However, it doesn't solve my problem. The user may be using either positional or keyword arguments, and both must be supported. I will just handle them differently.

Comment: OK, this is an XY problem. *Why* would you want to treat them differently? Do you just want to do something like `warnings.warn("deprecated", "'name' will be positional-only in the future")`?

Comment: I agree that you could see this as an XY problem. The thing is, my exact problem is quite complicated and hacky. I boiled it down to the essentials, and I think I framed my question quite clearly. I got the answer I was looking for!

Comment: I think you are *missing* the essentials. To be clear, your function should not behave *differently* based on whether positional or keyword arguments are used. If you want to change to positional-only or keyword-only arguments for one or both parameters, fine, but don't give either type a semantic meaning they were never intended to have.

Comment: I think my little intro with the deprecation threw you guys off. If you read from `I need to know whether...` it is really quite clear. In any case, I will keep your feedback in mind for my next question. As you can see I'm quite new here (long-time lurker though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `*args` to your function's arguments and check if that contains any arguments - if yes, the user passed positional arguments to your function that should have been passed as keyword arguments:

```py
def store(*args, name='', value=0):
    if args: # args is not empty - user passed deprecated positional arguments
        print(f"Warning: you passed the arguments {' and '.join(map(str, args))} as positional arguments.")
        print("This is deprecated - please pass them as keyword arguments")
        name = args[0]
        if len(args) >= 2:
            value = args[1]

store('ben', 5)
store(name='ben', value=5)
```

Tested in the interactive Python console:

```py
>>> store('ben', 5)
Warning: you passed the arguments ben and 5 as positional arguments.
This is deprecated - please pass them as keyword arguments
>>> store('ben', value=5)
Warning: you passed the arguments ben as positional arguments.
This is deprecated - please pass them as keyword arguments
>>> store(name='ben', value=5)
>>>
```

Comment: There's a third possibility, `store('ben', value=5)`, which this would not handle correctly.

Comment: @chepner did you test it ? If yes, you must have got the wrong code - the last version of the code only raised an error with your test case, which I fixed now.

Comment: Yes, your new code fixes that problem. However, you are assuming that it's the positional arguments, not the keyword arguments, that are deprecated.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Using the `*args` argument allows me to know exactly which parameters were passed as positional arguments, and still execute the function normally. Accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a decorator that contains all the deprecation-checking logic:

```
from functools import wraps


def _positional_arg_warning(args, func):
    varnames = func.__code__.co_varnames

    pos_varnames = ', '.join(varnames[:len(args)])

    msg = (
        f'Warning: positional arguments `{pos_varnames}` for `{func.__qualname__}` '
        'are deprecated.  Please use keyword arguments instead.'
    )
    print(msg)


def args_deprecated(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # call the function first, to make sure the signature matches
        ret_value = func(*args, **kwargs)

        if args:
            _positional_arg_warning(args, func)

        return ret_value
    return wrapper
```

Now you can wrap *any* function that will have its positional arguments deprecated:

```
@args_deprecated
def some_func(a, b, c=None):
    pass

>>> some_func('aa', 'bb', c='cc')
Warning: positional arguments a, b for `some_func` are deprecated.  
Please use keyword arguments instead.
>>>
>>> some_func(a='aa', b='bb', c='cc')
>>>
```

Comment: Neat! Somehow, decorators are not really in my 'system' yet. Will keep this possibility in mind.